# Is it possible to save data to file using pipe and unzip it in same time?

Tags: linux, pipe, gzip, tar

I'm trying to construct something like:

```
wget -qO- $source | <save_to_file> | <read_from_file> | tar -xzvf -
```

Main idea is to download original file and extract it in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
wget -qO- $source | tee copy.tar.gz | tar -xzvf -
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, Sergei! Огромное человеческое спасибо!